# How do I download files from a server and display them in a view?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to accomplish two things in my Android app:

- Download files from Server (pdf, image, and html)
- Once files downloaded, save all the files from server and display in Android Tab view

My question is, how can I download a file from a server and display it in my app?

My download code looks like this:

```
public void downloadFiles () {

        try {

            URL url = new URL ("http://google.com/nexuspads.png");
            HttpURLConnection c = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            c.setRequestMethod("GET");
            c.setDoOutput(true);
            c.connect();

            String PATH = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/download/" ;

            Log.v ("LOG_TAG" , "PATH: " + PATH);
            File file = new File (PATH);
            file.mkdirs();

            String fileName = "image.png";

            File outputFile = new File (file, fileName);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);

            InputStream is = c.getInputStream();

            byte[] buffer = new byte [1024];

            int len1 = 0 ;

            while ((len1 = is.read(buffer)) != -1){

                fos.write (buffer, 0, len1);
            }

            fos .close();
            is.close();

        }catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d ("LOG_TAG2 ", "Error " + e );
//          Toast.makeText(,"error " +e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();      
        }

    }
```

Comment: I have tried to download files from server and now i'm tryig to find a way to make this file view in android application activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To list the files in a folder it can be done as follows..

```
String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/YOUR folder here/";
            File f = new File(path);        
            final File listfile[] = f.listFiles();      
            String[] fileList = new String[listfile.length];
            for (int i=0; i < listfile.length; i++)     
            {
                fileList[i] =  listfile[i].getName();
                Log.v("Files", "FileName:" + listfile[i].getName());  
            }
```

you then could display the results in Alert Dialog or in an ListView.